# Fixed: CKEditor plugins not working with django-ckeditor

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I wanted to install easyimage plugin. I unpacked zip file to plugins folder so it's in `static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/easyimage`

settings.py

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'



CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['EasyImageUpload']
        ],
        'width': '100%',
        'height': 100,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(
            [
               'easyimage','
               'dialog',
               'balloontoolbar',
               'cloudservices',
               'button'
            ]
        ),

    },
```

and i still get error `GET http://192.168.0.3:8000/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/easyimage/plugin.js?t=K5H9 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

`ckeditor.js:270 Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "easyimage" was not found at "http://192.168.0.3:8000/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/easyimage/plugin.js?t=K5H9".`

Edit:
forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
from ckeditor_uploader.widgets import CKEditorUploadingWidget

class TaskDescriptionForm(forms.Form):
    description = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())

    class Meta:
        fields = ['description']
```

models.py

`description = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)`

Edit2: I added dependencies, but I still get 404.
Edit3: I had my plugins in wrong directory

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: yeah, i think i had it in wrong directory, because i had 2 plugins directories (from collectstatic and normal, created by me), but I don't remember more. You can try installing plugins in both directories if you have 2.

Comment: I also had it in the wrong directory.